# Can't run a c++ cgi on Kubuntu 10. Checked all apache configurations+exec+cgi-bin+api

Tags: c++, apache2, cgi, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to compile my 1st c++ cgi Programm on kubuntu 10 with Apache2 but nothing.

I've Put it to the cgi-bin folder checked the config files, run the programm on command, changed privileges to executable, but nothing.
Rekonq says 'No service can handle this file'

I've apt get instal apache2. Have restarted it also. Nuts

Its been all day now and gone desperate. If you have any idea, will save me

My cgi-bin is in etc/apache2/. 
My config file @ etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
To another answer these were the wright for Kub10-12

You can see all configurations and execution in this screenshoot. Copy here also
http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/1659/cgiv.jpg

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access your CGI program directly via the filesystem (with `file://` URLs), which means Apache is not servicing your request.

Instead, connect to Apache running on the localhost with the URL `http://localhost/cgi-bin/cplusplus.cgi`.

Comment: OMG IT WORKS! Of course like with PhP scripts, howw fool and noobish could be that!!! So thank you sorry for bothering with such a stupid question and so thank you again that you bothered replying!!!